# SAS - always round up to two decimal places?

Tags: sas, rounding

Im trying to round a decimal that is currently 4 places into two but rounding up always.

As an example 0.2407 should round to 0.25.
Is there a way to do this? Ceil is integer only and round(x,0.01) returns 0.24 as expected.

Comment: Would this help:  `y = ceil (x*100) / 100;`?

Comment: Thanks so much! Not sure why i didnt think of that, must have been staring at the code for too long! @EgorLipchinskiy

Comment: @EgorLipchinskiy Add an answer with your comment, then Jake can select it, and I can give it an upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solution could be:

```
y = ceil (x*100) / 100;
```

Example:

```
data a;
  x = 0.2407;
  y = ceil (x*100) / 100;
  put x= y=;
run;
```

Log:

```
x=0.2407 y=0.25
```